# Checking if an element exists in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, element

There is a particular page having a number - which is a link to a list. I want to be able to search for the count. If the count is 0, then do nothing, else click on on the number to open the list.

I am using the isPresent() function in Protractor to search for it.

My code is

```
$('cda-e2e-softwareCountZero').isPresent().then(function(result) {

if ( result ) {
    // No Software    
} else {
    element(by.id('cda-e2e-softwareCount')).click();
}

});
```

However, this always returns the following error

Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

How do I solve this issue?

Edit:

The HTML Code for the same is

```
<span class="panelHead">
                            Softwares
                            <a ng-if="summaryMetaDataList.softwares.length != 0" 
                                ng-href="/application/application/{{summaryMetaDataInfo.entityId || alternateText}}/software/list{{dateParamsUrl}}">
                                <span style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">(</span><span class="textUnderlineBlue" id="cda-e2e-softwareCount">{{summaryMetaDataList.softwares.length}}</span><span style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">)</span>
                            </a>
                            <a ng-if="summaryMetaDataList.softwares.length == 0">
                                <span style="color: black" id="cda-e2e-softwareCountZero">({{summaryMetaDataList.softwares.length}})</span>
                            </a>
</span>
```

Comment: paste HTML code. It would be easy to help you

Comment: Added the HTML code for your reference too

Comment: Locator should like this $('#cda-e2e-softwareCountZero'). Try with this locator

Comment: @SureshSalloju The same error still persists. (A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.) But at the end of the time out, the link is clicked. How do i get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase Jasmine time out on conf.js file. Follow the below code

```
  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 12000
  },
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! But I had to set a very high value. Why does it take so long to enter the else block?

Comment: your application may have lot of polling requests. that makes execution slow. If your solution work for you tick my answer